# Get always returns null

Tags: c#, caching, memory

My problem is that adding a ChangeMonitor prevents the cache. `Get` always returns null instead of data.

Without the monitor, the data will be returned.

Has anyone an idea for this behavior?

```
try {
    var x = cache.Get(key);

    if (x != null) {
        extendedList = x as List<HistoryInformation>;
        return extendedList;
    }
    data = await _client.NewGetAllLocationHistoryAsync(data);

    list.AddRange(data.List);

    extendedList = extendHistoryList(list);

    CacheItemPolicy policy = new CacheItemPolicy()
    {
        SlidingExpiration = new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0, 0)
    };

    // By the next four lines of code the cache.Get function always returns null!!!

    policy.ChangeMonitors.Add(cache.CreateCacheEntryChangeMonitor(new string[] { cacheName }));
    policy.RemovedCallback = args => {
        log.Info($"GetHistory:{args.CacheItem.Key} ---> {args.RemovedReason}.");
    };

    var v = cache.Add(key, extendedList, policy);

    // Returns null if the lines  "policy.ChangeMonitors.Add ...
    // and                        "policy.RemovedCallback" part of the code.
    var y = cache.Get(key);
}
```

Comment: Did you read the documentation on cache monitors? It seems to be a rather complicated thing, so I wouldn't rely on just winging it.

Comment: Quoting: "Not all cache implementations support cache-entry change monitors. To determine whether your cache implementation supports CacheEntryChangeMonitor objects, see the documentation for the specific cache implementation." What cache are you using? Does it support cache entry change monitor objects?

Comment: Thanks for reply. I am using memory cache (```ObjectCache cache = MemoryCache.Default;```).  So far i understand the windows documentation. Memory Cache supports the CacheEntryChangeMOnitor (https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.runtime.caching.memorycache.createcacheentrychangemonitor?view=netframework-4.6.2).

Comment: Are you sure `cache.Get` is returning null? It looks more like you're getting an exception that you're ignoring and returning null instead. Can you produce a minimal complete example that reproduces the behaviour you're seeing?

Comment: Yes, that is the wired thing for me. I am catching the exceptions with catch (Exception e)
            {
                log.Error($"GetHistory: Exception {e.Message}");
            }.  But no exception was thrown. With the catch block and the cache declaration, it is already  a complete small example.

Comment: It maybe almost complete, but it isn't minimal - the point is to strip off everything that isn't related to the problem, giving something people can run immediately and see your problem :)

Comment: And there's critical complications that make it impossible to do anything about your sample - what is `cacheName`, and how does it relate to the items in the cache?

Comment: Sorry, cacheName and key are exactly the same.

Comment: Yeah, that's your problem. I guessed that and wrote my answer assuming that, so it should help you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You asked it to remove the item from the cache.

Caching is complicated. It's one of the things you should very carefuly implement according to documentation. As it happens, you're asking for things you do not want.

`ChangeMonitors` doesn't refer to objects monitoring *the cache*. It represents monitors that report when the cache needs to be invalidated. For example, if you have a file you want cached in-memory, you use a file change monitor, so when the file changes on the disk, it's immediately invalidated in the cache. For bonus points, `CacheEntryChangeMonitor` will immediately raise the removed notification if the key doesn't exist in the cache. Put these two behaviours together, and...

- You create a new cache policy, with a change monitor that monitors `cache` on key `cacheName`
- There is no key in the cache with the name specified by `cacheName`, so the change monitor immediately registers the item as removed
- You add a cache item with key `key`. This succeeds, and adds item to the cache. However, the change monitor says the item should be invalidated, so it's immediately removed from the cache.
- `Get(key)` returns null, as it's supposed to

In summary: If you want to monitor a cache for changes, use `RemovedCallback` or `CacheEntryChangeMonitor`. If you want to invalidate a cache item when something else changes, use `ChangeMonitors`.

Comment: thank you for your explication. When I understand you correctly, my first error was that I tried to monitor the cache itself, but the monitor is for monitoring the objects stored in the cache. If I understand you right, I had to monitor the my extendedList for example? But, then would the cache removed, if I call the function again, getting the list from the cache and adding an item to the extendedList? To be honest, I not really understand the windos example for the ChangeMonitor.

Comment: I think, I got it. The CacheEntryChangeMonitor is for situations, where a cached item (i.e. key1) depends from another cached item (key2) in the same cache. So, if some changes happens to the cache item (key2), the CacheEntryChangeMonitor, (monitoring key2 for key1) has to remove the cache item (key1), such that the cache item (key1) must be recreated.

Comment: Luaan, thank you for your help!!! Whether I still not allowed to visually vote your answer up, I hope other developer will do it.